# Get Multiple Entities from Symfony route annotation with the same column name

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations, symfony4

I have two Doctrine Entities. Project and Story, both of which have a unique column name Alias. I want to fetch both project and story entities (In this case i actually want only the Story object but the project alias will be dynamic). I tried with the `@Entity` property:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/project/{Alias}/{StoryAlias}", name="front-project-story-page" )
     * @Entity("Story", expr="repository.findBy(['Alias'=>StoryAlias])")
     */
    public function FrontProjectStoryPage(Project $project,Story $story)
    {
     ....
    }
```

But it prompts this error

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("[Semantical Error] Annotation @Entity is not allowed to be declared on method. 
You may only use this annotation on these code elements: CLASS in /home/../config/routes/../../src/Controller/ 
(which is being imported from "/home/../config/routes/annotations.yaml"). 
Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.").
```

How can i fetch entities that may have same column name?

Comment: While you might be able to get this to work with annotations, seems easier to just inject the repository and make a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation you can do like this

> mapping: Configures the properties and values to use with the findOneBy() method: the key is the route placeholder name and the value is the Doctrine property name:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{date}/{slug}/comments/{comment_slug}")
 * @ParamConverter("post", options={"mapping": {"date": "date", "slug": "slug"}})
 * @ParamConverter("comment", options={"mapping": {"comment_slug": "slug"}})
*/
public function showComment(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using `Doctrine\ORM\Annotation\Entity` instead of `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity`.

however, as someone else have mentioned, its also possible to achieve the same result using `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter` :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/project/{alias}/{story-alias}", name="front-project-story-page" )
     *
     * @ParamConverter("project", options={"mapping": {"alias": "alias"}})
     * @ParamConverter("story", options={"mapping": {"story-alias": "alias"}})
     */
    public function FrontProjectStoryPage(Project $project,Story $story)
    {
     ....
    }
```

read more : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#doctrineconverter-options

Comment: You were right, i was using the wrong class! Thanks a lot!